# using common table expressions in mysql

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

I am attempting to solve an HackerRank challenge and using `MySQL` query engine. I'd like to use `WITH` and `CTEs` for the problem.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/interviews/problem?isFullScreen=true

Here's what I wrote:

```
WITH contests AS (
  SELECT ct.contest_id, ct.hacker_id, ct.name, co.college_id
  FROM Contests ct
  LEFT JOIN Colleges co ON ct.contest_id = co.contest_id
  LEFT JOIN Challenges ch ON co.college_id = ch.college_id
),
Stats AS (
  SELECT 
    vs.challenge_id, 
    SUM(vs.total_views) as tv, 
    SUM(vs.total_unique_views) as tuv, 
    SUM(ss.total_submissions) as ts,
    SUM(ss.total_accepted_submissions) as tas
  FROM View_Stats vs
  JOIN Submission_Stats ss on vs.challenge_id = ss.challenge_id
  GROUP BY vs.challenge_id
)
SELECT contest_id, hacker_id, name, tv, tuv, ts, tas
FROM contests
JOIN Stats ON contests.challenge_id = Stats.challenge_id
HAVING SUM(tv + tuv + ts + tas) > 0;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'contests AS (
SELECT ct.contest_id, ct.hacker_id, ct.name, co.college_id
' at line 1

What is the right syntax for the query to work?

Comment: they use an older version of mysql that doesn't support CTE, they are antiquated in many regards

Comment: @nbk I think different questions may use different versions, it's very strange

Comment: do `select @@version;`; you will need version 8

Comment: @ysth `5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`